# Angular 2 AOT: Cannot find name

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-aot

I've been having a hard time figuring out how to get a global third-party library to be accessible in my Ng2/Typescript project. I don't know if which library it is matters much, but for the record, it's SVGMorpheus, which does not have any sort of module definition (AMD or Angular), nor does it have .d.ts files.

That's all fine: I am able to do the standard thing that you're supposed to do when importing these files - add it to the angular-cli.json file under the "scripts" section. That gets the project to build and compile fine.

However, it seems as though AOT is breaking it. When I compile, I get:

```
ERROR in [path-to-component-under-nda].ts(24,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SVGMorpheus'.
[path-to-component-under-nda].ts(41,21): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SVGMorpheus'.
child_process.js:644
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but it doesn't seem like there are any other suggestions on how to fix it since as far as I can tell I'm doing this correctly. As far as I can tell, CLI grabs global libs that are declared like this at the beginning of the build process. I'm not sure why it's breaking. Does anyone have any hints or clues (or straight up experience) with this particular problem?

**EDIT**
I've also added a definition in the typings.d.ts file:

```
declare interface SVGMorpheusOptions {
  iconId?: string;
  duration?: number;
  easing?: string;
  rotation?: string;
}

declare class SVGMorpheus {
  constructor(element: HTMLElement | HTMLIFrameElement | Object, options?: SVGMorpheusOptions, callback?: () => void);

  to: (icon: string) => void;
}
```

Comment: You could try declaring the var: declare var SVGMorpheus: any; to suppress the error. Or you could write your own types definition for this package.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already did that. I'll edit the original answer but basically yes, I already added it to the typings.d.ts file to no avail.

Comment: You are not exporting the declared classes yet, did you try that too?

Comment: As in `export declare class SVGMorpheus`...? Yes I have tried all flavors of exporting that I know exist.... :(